# Correctly wrap text in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, tableview

I want to ask if anybody have solution for this kind of problem:

**I have Tableview with dynamic cells, they have two labels and dynamic height. When the data is set to label, text in label is splitting in to new rows in the middle of word. [image: See the picture]**

1. I tried set line breaking to word wrapping

[image: (settings of label)]

2. In other tableviews with dynamic cell height I have no problem with splitting text
3. Labels have constraints to top, bottom, left and right of content view
4. Newest Xcode version and iOS > 13.0

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In the picture of settings you can see the number of lines is set to 0 :/

Comment: I suspect it is a problem with orphan control, where the layout engine is trying to avoid a situation where you end up with one word on a line in the middle of the text block. It may help if you allow the second label to also wrap and make it narrower, so there is a bit more width for the first label

Comment: I changed the width of the second label and set the same settings to it. Same situation... nothing changed

Comment: It would help if you could create a [mcve] project somewhere

Comment: I make a little project, https://files.fm/u/zjzspvee

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. If I use a long string with non-accented characters (just English words), then the behaviour is correct.  If I use a few accented characters then it also works. It looks like they don't account for accented characters correctly somehow. If I use your sample text in one row, then that row shows the issue.  If you have a paid developer support agreement you might want to use one of your tech support incidents as you already have a minimal example to share, but sometimes they end up saying "Yep, it's a bug, submit a radar".   I would submit a radar anyway.

Comment: Thank you! I have a lot of table views in my project and only this one have some kind of bug. Yes I am paid developer so I will raise a ticket. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I download your demo and tried the same settings in English Language and it worked perfectly , so it seems a bug for me in Xcode for me ..

Comment: Unfortunately , yes !